# python strStr II not working

Tags: python-3.x, strstr

I am doing the strStr II problem on Lintcode. For the input ("abcdef","bcd"), the output is -1, which is different from the expected value, 1. I did some debug process and found that the way I did could not get the same code value for the 'bcd' in the source and 'bcd' in the target. I just don't know what's going on.

```
def strStr2(self, source, target):
    if source is None or target is None:
        return -1
    m = len(target)
    if m == 0:
        return 0
    n = len(source)
    base = 1000000
    power = 1

    for i in range(m - 1):
        power = 26 * power % base

    targetcode = 0
    for i in range(m):
        targetcode = (targetcode * 26 + ord(target[i]) - ord('a')) % base
        if targetcode < 0:
            targetcode += base

    sourcecode = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sourcecode = (sourcecode * 26 + ord(source[i]) - ord('a')) % base
        if i >= m:
            sourcecode = (sourcecode - ord(source[i-m]) * power - ord('a')) % base
        if sourcecode < 0:
            sourcecode += base
        if sourcecode == targetcode:
            if source[i - m + 1, i + 1] == target:
                return i - m + 1

    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you are trying to implement Rabin-Karp algorithm. There are a few errors in your code. Here is a commented version with the fixes.

Also, I believe you would gain efficiency by reducing hash collisions if your chose `1000000` and `26` to be prime numbers instead.

```
def strStr2(source, target):
    # There is no need to check that source and target are not None
    # Also, storing  lengths as m and n only makes the code harder to read

    if len(target) == 0:
        return 0

    base = 1000000
    power = 1

    for i in range(len(target)):  # Your range was incorrect
        power = 26 * power % base

    targetcode = 0
    for i in range(len(target)):
        # There is no need to normalize your chars at 'a'
        # That would not work for uppercase anyway
        targetcode = (targetcode * 26 + ord(target[i])) % base


    sourcecode = 0
    for i in range(len(source)):
        sourcecode = (sourcecode * 26 + ord(source[i])) % base
        if i >= len(target):
            # In the line below was an error in your priority of operation
            sourcecode = (sourcecode - ord(source[i-len(target)]) * power) % base

        # you do not need to check that sourcecode is < 0, since base is > 0

        if sourcecode == targetcode:
            # For slicing use : instead of , in Python
            if source[i - len(target) + 1:i + 1] == target:
                return i - len(target) + 1

    return -1
```

And here are a few example to show it works.

```
strStr2("abcdef","bcd") # 1
strStr2("aaaabcdef","bcd") # 4
strStr2("abcdef","bcda") # -1
```